# Remove checkbox-menu Ag-Grid - VueJs - NodeJs

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I need to remove this checkbox from my menu, can anyone help me?

[image]

I am using "VueJS".

My current code:

```
            {
                headerName: "",
                width: 30,
                checkboxSelection: true,
                suppressMenu: true,
                filter: false,
                floatingFilterComponentParams: { suppressFilterButton: true }
            },
```

https://prnt.sc/q8d4ci

Comment: Try with `checkboxSelection: false`.

Comment: I need to disable checkbox for header only. This "checkboxSelection" option removes for the entire column, needed to remove only from the header.

Comment: Actually this box that appears in the image is the column filter, not the checkbox. Excuse me.

Comment: @TGrif up, can help-me?

Comment: Hard to tell without the relevant part of your script, but I think you need to change it in the header table option. Maybe add `filter: false` to it then. I don't know much about that particular library.